# Strrev behaving weirdly in C

Tags: c, reverse

I am new to C programming . I was writing a program to implement big integer addition by representing integers in an array. I put printf everywhere in my main program and figured out that the strrev part is what is causing the problem(i only put the erroneous part here and not the main program obviously. But I cannot figure out what is going wrong.  Can anyone please help me with the same?

Code below-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct integer
{
    char store[200];
    int length;
};
void printer2(struct integer x1);
int main()
{

struct integer x1;
x1.store[0]=1;
x1.store[1]=2;
x1.store[2]=3;
x1.store[3]=4;
x1.store[4]=5;
x1.length=5; 
printer2(x1);
strrev(x1.store);
printer2(x1);
return 0; 
}

void printer2(struct integer a1)
{
    int j;
    for (j=0;j<a1.length;j++)
    {
        printf("a1 %d is %d\n",j,a1.store[j]);
    }
};
```

Comment: You know that `1` is not the same as `'1'`, right? And that `x1` is uninitialized, right?

Comment: Nice I liked the part "i put print everywhere"...nice going

Answer (score 1):

A C string is an array of `char`s terminated by a nul (`'\0'\`) element.  You are missing this terminator from your array so `strrev` will read on until it finds the first zero byte.  Or your program crashes.

If you want to treat your array as a string, you need to add a nul terminator to it

```
x1.store[5]='\0';
```

As pointed out by Jongware, note that this approach will fail if you want to set any array elements to `0` - these would be mis-interpreted as a nul terminator.  If you'll be printing out the characters, you maybe want the character code for integers instead - `'0'`, `'1'`, etc.

As an aside, note that functions like

```
void printer2(struct integer a1)
```

are passed a complete copy of `a1`.  If this isn't deliberate, you could consider passing the address of the caller's instance instead

```
void printer2(const struct integer* a1)
```

which is called using the address operator `&`

```
printer2(&x1);
```

Comment: This will only make it work as long as there are no *other* zeroes elsewhere in the result.

Comment: Thanks. I m sorry for noob question. I just started C programming yesterday. I fail to understand why my program worked perfectly with 3 numbers instead of 5 though

Comment: @AkashRupela It didn't work perfectly, it only seemed to work. The program invokes undefined behavior as-is, you can't reason about what it does.

Comment: @AkashRupela Reading uninitialised memory results in undefined behaviour.  One valid (if unhelpful) example of this is that your program appears to work, only to later fail when you make a small change.

Answer (score 0):

This anwser is after the anwser above. I only give a suggestion.

May be you can store **a digit of your integer** by `char` .Initialized them like:

```
x1.store[0]='1';
x1.store[1]='2';
x1.store[2]='3';
x1.store[3]='4';
x1.store[4]='5';
x1.store[5]='\0'
x1.length=5;
```

When use a digit of integer. use  `int x1_store0 = x1.store[0] - '0';`

Comment: The funny thing is that since `length` is provided, you *can* actually store literal decimal values. The problem is, to use string functions you need to work with strings. And then you don't *have* to save the length as well. (Although caching it might save some time over having to use `strlen` every time you need it.)